# T-SQL - Getting a list of records depending on other related records values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make a query and need a little help (SQL Server).

Imagine the following scenario: user is viewing a web page which has several related categories. According to some rules, the page should not be displayed if a specific category has been put together with another category.

For this I've got 2 tables:

1) Has the page Id and the related categories:

```
Pk  CategoryNumber
--------------------
1   30
1   31
1   45
2   30
3   21
3   26
3   64
4   25
4   12
5   25
5   31
5   30
5   45
```

2) Rules table. First row means: when viewing a page with the category 30 it should not be retrieved if it **also** has the 45 category.

```
WhenViewingCategoryNumber   HideEverythingWithCategoryNumber
-------------------------------------------------------
30                      45
25                      31
```

Output expected:

```
2
3
4
```

I've spent a few hours around this and I'm not going anywhere, so I would appreciate if someone could help. If possible, would be better an answer with a SELECT statement to integrate it directly within a larger CTE statement. Many thanks.

Comment: Your explanation of the rules table is not consistent with the names of the columns.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you substituted `Pk` with `PageId`. `Pk` usually stands for primary key, which apparently is not the case with your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query to identify those page ids related to conflicting categories:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.PageId
FROM Categories AS c1
INNER JOIN Rules AS r ON c1.ItemNumber = r.WhenViewingCategoryNumber   
INNER JOIN Categories AS c2 ON c1.PageId = c2.PageId 
                     AND r.HideEverythingWithCategoryNumber = c2.ItemNumber
```

This will return:

```
PageId
------
1
5
```

Now you can get expected result by simply using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PageId
FROM Categories 
WHERE PageId NOT IN ( ... above query here ....)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bfd7f/1)